# CodeIgniter-Inner Join 5 or more Tables (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 5 tables and I want to inner join them but my codes doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
$query = $this->db->select('tblmastersection.*, tblsavesection.*,tblmastersecmolecular.*,tblmastersecpathology.*,tblmastersecparasitology.* ')
          ->from('tblmastersection')
          ->join('tblsavesection', 'tblmastersection.section_id = tblsavesection.section_id', 'inner')
           ->join('tblmastersecmolecular', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecmolecular.test_id', 'inner')
          ->join('tblmastersecparasitology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecparasitology.test_id', 'inner')
            ->join('tblmastersecpathology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecpathology.test_id', 'inner')
            ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Join one by one and see the results, so you can find which table caused the issue, OR post all the related table in your post with sample data.

Comment: Please post your table structure and output of your query.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the `select` call. Query Builder is probably not "escaping" your list of fields correctly which results in an invalid statement.

Since you want all fields from all five tables this should work.

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('tblmastersection')
    ->join('tblsavesection', 'tblmastersection.section_id=tblsavesection.section_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecmolecular', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecmolecular.test_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecparasitology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecparasitology.test_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecpathology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecpathology.test_id', 'inner')
    ->get();

return $query->result();
```

The above can be made a little bit more concise and still produce the same result. The Query Builder method `get()` can accept the name of a table. So use

```
->get('tblmastersection')
```

instead of

```
->from('tblmastersection')
//and later in the chain
->get()
```

Also, know that if a `select()` method is not provided then `SELECT *` is assumed.

Lastly, assigning the return from the chained methods to `$query` provides no benefit unless you want to check that `$query` is valid before using it. Since you're not checking `$query` don't use it. Just go ahead and add `->result()` to the chain and return the outcome immediately.

Here's the rewrite using that knowledge.

```
return $this->db
    ->join('tblsavesection', 'tblmastersection.section_id=tblsavesection.section_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecmolecular', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecmolecular.test_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecparasitology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecparasitology.test_id', 'inner')
    ->join('tblmastersecpathology', 'tblsavesection.test_id = tblmastersecpathology.test_id', 'inner')
    ->get('tblmastersection')
    ->result();
```